# Unable to start client while Alexa setup on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to setup Alexa on my Raspberry Pi by following instruction given [here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/wiki/Raspberry-Pi)

But I am getting Java Exception while starting Client (`mvn exec:exec`)

Below is the terminal Output when I executed `mvn exec:exec`, I have tried all the related threads but nothing worked.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Alexa Voice Service Sample Java Client 20160207.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ sample-java-client ---
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1321)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1296)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1348)
    at com.amazon.alexa.avs.App.<init>(App.java:67)
    at com.amazon.alexa.avs.App.<init>(App.java:53)
    at com.amazon.alexa.avs.App.main(App.java:48)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at com.amazon.alexa.avs.ui.MainWindow.<init>(MainWindow.java:41)
    at com.amazon.alexa.avs.App.createViews(App.java:91)
    at com.amazon.alexa.avs.App.lambda$new$0(App.java:67)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I tried s`udo mvn -e install` also, in that case build succeeded but I am not getting the popup with the URL for with registration token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same (I believe) issue. It's caused when you can't access the X window. I suspect that you're SSHing into the Pi. If this is the case, you want to make sure that [X forwarding is set up](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=11237), and then connect to the Pi with the -X flag: `ssh -X IP_ADDRESS` and if you try again, you should be able to get your popups now! Good luck!

Comment: Yes, this was the issue, I haven't tried using `ssh -X` but now I am using Alexa with **VNC Connection**